# PHP: Why does 0 == "v2"?

Tags: php, dynamic

I came across a defect in my software caused by: `0 == "v2"` is `true`

Firstly that seems crazy but I'm sure theres some weird conversion going on. I need a way to compare two values without specific types, i.e.:

`0 == "v2"` is `false`

`0 == "0"` is `true`

But the `===` operator will not work in the second case. Is there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: loosely typed comparisons... [read all about it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: To solve the problem you mention, check `(string) $value1 === (string) $value2`.